# Is it correct to use "take" in "I took this word from the dictionary"?

Tags: word-usage

Let's suppose I am translating a text from my native language into English, and I come across a word that I don't know how to translate. I look it up in the dictionary and put it in my text. Can I say that I *took* that word from the dictionary, or should I use a different verb?

Comment: You might consider _"I found this word in [name of dictionary]"_.

Comment: *Found*, *got*, *located*... all are fine, as is *took*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "take" or "took" is fine here and is commonly used for this idea.

Comment: Took functions correctly, but sounds odd, at least to me (NAmE). More often than not, I hear that someone **got** a word from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

“Got” and “found” are all good examples but not for every use of “took” in a sentence. 
If you were saying “It took me forever to finish the project.” Or “It took a long time for me to finish the test.”

Then what would you say is another word you could use to substitute “took” in those sentences?

Comment: Are you suggesting “Got” and “found”?